# Getting items from different sources in parallel and returning the result

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, task-parallel-library

I have some code that looks something similar to this:

```
    public IList<Result> GetResult()
    {
        var result = new List<Result>();

        result.AddRange(GetSomeItemsA());
        result.AddRange(GetSomeItemsB());
        result.AddRange(GetSomeItemsC());

        return result;
    }
```

I would like to call the methods GetSomeItemsA, GetSomeItemsB and GetSomeItemsC using the Task Parallel Library or make it faster some other way, then return the result only when the three tasks are completed.

In general, what would be the best approach, how can it be optimized when we need to get items from different sources then return the result containing all the items from this sources?

Comment: Does `GetSomeItems` return a `Task<Result>`? What version of .NET?

Comment: Hi, no, it doesn't return a Task<Result> at the moment. Version 4.0 of .NET. The three methods that I am calling I want to be called in parallel, so that I don't wait for method A to complete in order to call method B to get my items.

Comment: Do the items have to be in the same order they are now (i.e. items from A first, then from B, then from C)?

Comment: No, the order doesn't matter, when I have the result I can sort them the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PLINQ to do this:

```
public IList<Result> GetResult()
{
    return new Func<IEnumerable<Result>>[] { GetSomeItemsA, GetSomeItemsB, GetSomeItemsC  }
        .AsParallel()
        .SelectMany(f => f())
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like the following:

```
        var result = new List<Result>();

        var firstTask = new Task<IEnumerable<Result>>(this.GetSomeItemsA);
        var secondTask = new Task<IEnumerable<Result>>(this.GetSomeItemsB);
        var thirdTask = new Task<IEnumerable<Result>>(this.GetSomeItemsC);
        firstTask.Start();
        secondTask.Start();
        thirdTask.Start();

        Task.WaitAll(firstTask, secondTask, thirdTask);

        result.AddRange(firstTask.Result);
        result.AddRange(secondTask.Result);
        result.AddRange(thirdTask.Result);

        return result;
```

Comment: Instead of first creating the `Task` and the `Start()`ing it, you can just call `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.